# How can I confirm individual changes in a project-wide find and replace?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I'm in project search (Shift + CMD + F) I can search the whole project for a specific word or expression. I can also enter a word I would like to replace it with.

If I click on one of the search results, it shows me the current version and the replacement version side by side. However, I can't find a way to confirm the replacement instance by instance! I only see a button to replace ALL instances, which is usually not what I want to do.

The reason is that certain words might be used in different context throughout the project, so usually not all search results shall be replaced.

How can I confirm the replacement instance by instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The replace one is on the each item that showing when mouse moved on each item.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative approach, you can press `CMD + D` repeatedly to select successive instances of a match, and `CMD + SHIFT + D` to skip any instance you do not want to include, and in this way case by case include each match in your find \ replace.

Also useful is `CMD + U` to undo the last selection action, in case you screw up during this process so you don't need to start over.  Note, your shortcuts may be vary per operating system, but the procedure is the same.

Comment: Which commands do you mean exactly? Can you record your shortcuts under Preferences --> Keyboard Shortcuts and show me which commands they resolve to? `CMD + SHIFT + D` resolves to `View: Show Debug` which is probably not the command you mean.